# BigQuery != "null" is it a Bug?

Tags: google-bigquery

Set up the following data:

```
create table `<YOUR PROJECT>.exampledata.whatnulls`
AS (SELECT '' col1
UNION ALL SELECT null col1
UNION ALL SELECT 'null' col1
UNION ALL SELECT 'notnull' col1);
```

Perform this query:

```
select 'col1 is null' predicate, count(*) n
from `testset-2021.exampledata.whatnulls`
where col1 is null 
union all
select 'col1 = "null"' predicate, count(*)
from `testset-2021.exampledata.whatnulls`
where col1 = "null" 
union all
select 'col1 is not null' predicate, count(*)
from `testset-2021.exampledata.whatnulls`
where col1 is not null 
union all
select 'col1 != "null"' predicate, count(*)
from `testset-2021.exampledata.whatnulls`
where col1 != "null"
```

The result:

```
predicate        | n
---------------------   
col1 != "null"   | 2
col1 is null     | 1
col1 is not null | 3
col1 = "null"    | 1
```

Why is `col1 != "null"` matching 2 values rather than 3? Is this a bug in Big Query?

Comment: It's really curious but i guess that the issue is with the type looking at the doc https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators. Can you check which type is assigned to col1 and see if it changes per row?

Comment: NULLABLE STRING, but still "null" is not the same as `NULL`

I'm not sure how it would change per row, or how to check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because for most SQL functions (here `!=` is a type of comparison function), when input is `NULL`, the output is also `NULL`

```sql
SELECT CAST(NULL AS STRING) != "null" -- giving you NULL instead of false
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it in MySQL and got the same results.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02f639/3